# Need help installing and using PHP/Imap

Tags: php

I install php/imap through composer
[image]

response after install
[image]

Installed package and site directory

[image]

PHP file code
[image]

fatal error response
[image]

Help solve fatal error

PHP v7.4

what am I doing wrong?

[Changed the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfyx5.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igfsN.png)

Comment: Please don't paste links to images.

Comment: Posted an update. Basically, you need to get your paths right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to autoload your vendor directory. Not sure what namespace that package uses so you might need to `use ...` under that, or fully qualify that package if you haven't done so.

```
<?php 

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

...
```

## Update

[image]

Notice, it is looking for the `vendor` directory inside your `www` directory so you can either,

1. run `composer require...` from inside your `www` directory. This will generate the `vendor` directory inside the `www` directory, or
2. change the path to account for the vendor directory being up a directory. Ex. `require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';`. Notice the `/../`

If I were you, I'd go with #1 and have the `vendor` directory inside you `www`. This is the standard way to do things.